# Checking That Only Digits are Used in a Command-line Argument

Tags: c

I am working on a program that accepts one command-line argument and I only want it to accept digits. I want it to return 1 and print "Usage: ./caesar key" if there is anything that is not a digit for example if the user inputs 20x in the command line instead of 20. I have created a code for it but find that it returns 1 and prints "Usage: ./caesar key" no matter what even if the command line argument contains only digits. Does anyone have some advice as to how to fix this?

```
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(argv[1]); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit((char)argv[i]) == false)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
            printf("\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("success");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `isdigit((char)argv[i])` --> `isdigit(argv[1][i])`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks I am still fairly new to command-line arguments and arrays so I've been stuck on this all day. This seemed to have fixed it!

Comment: It is clear now why it fixes things?

Comment: But `isdigit(argv[1][i])` only checks the first character of the parameter and not the whole thing, doesn't it?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes - only 1 character

Comment: So something like this then: https://onlinegdb.com/B1-dvM7-_

Answer (score 0):

1. The return value of `isdigit` is an integer and not a
   boolean, so you're likely to not get an appropriate result to your
   comparison. The return value can be used like a boolean in some
   ways, but not for direct value comparison.  You don't need the
   direct value comparison here in C anyway, so just deleting  `== false` from your code and putting a `!` in front of `isdigit` is the
   best thing.
2. If you removed the `(char)` cast from `argv[i]` then the
   compiler would tell you that you're using a pointer as an integer
   without a cast.  This is because argv is an array of pointers (kind
   of like a 2 dimensional array in its use, but with some
   differences).  When you index this value only once then you get a
   pointer which has to be indexed again to get a character that you
   pass into isdigit.  A helpful way to keep this straight would be to
   declare a `const char *` variable that you set equal to `argv[1]`
   before your loop and then use it within the loop instead of worrying
   about the extra stuff that goes along with using argv directly.
3. You are not handling the case of `argv[1]` being `""` or
   `NULL` (though you might have done your `NULL` test earlier).
4. Since you're going to be looping through the string (char[])
   anyway, and strlen has to loop through the string to find the end,
   you could change the whole loop not know its bounds up front and
   just check for the `'\0'` and then do the `isdigit` test.